# Bulk Changing Sharing in Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to change (add & remove) various shares in many files on my Google Drive. I think I can do this as a "side-effect" of a Sheets script. That is, I can iterate through a file list and change sharing by reading existing shares, adding what I need and removing others. Something like this, sort of (mildly related snippet):

```
var newFile = oldFile.makeCopy(strFilename, folder);
var owner =   DriveApp.getFileById(stremplateID).getOwner();
newFile.setOwner(owner);                // Keep original owner
var arrViewers = oldFile.getViewers();  // Keep all original viewers
if (arrViewers.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrViewers.length; i++) {
    newFile.addViewer(arrViewers[i]);
  }
}
```

My question is, is this best done as a script associated with a spreadsheet? Is there a better way to create a utility script like this? Sorry if my question is a bit open-ended.

Comment: A "Stand Alone" Script can be created.  A Stand Alone script is visible in your Google Drive.  An Apps Script that is *bound* to a Doc, Sheet, Form is not visible in your Google Drive.  So, I suppose one issue to consider is how you find what you are looking for.  There is no easy way to get the code out of an Apps Script file that is bound to a document, you must copy everything out.  So, if you want to share or make copies, or download a copy of the script, you might prefer a stand alone script.  If you want to prevent users from seeing the spreadsheet, use stand alone HTML Service.